# Screenshot the top most layer/view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, screenshot, layer

I have a `UIView` which contains another `UIView` with an `UIImage`.

```
    dView=[[drawView alloc]initWithFrame:myUIView.frame];
    [dView newMaskWithColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:chosenImage]];
    [myUIView addSubview:dView];
```

And by using [this](https://github.com/craighowarth/WipeAwayView) code, I erased a part of it, and it looks like this now:
[image]

and now I added a `layer` behind this view, and presented another `image` in that `layer`.

```
 [myUIView.layer insertSublayer:_videoPreviewLayer below:dView.layer];
```

and now it looks like this: (this is the screenshot manually taken on device)

[image]

When I try to screenshot the above view programmatically, the result is[image]:

I dont why the newly added videopreview layer doesnt appeared in the screenshot.Here is my screenshot method.

```
-(void)takeSnapShot{

 UIView *topView = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] subviews] lastObject];  //tried this too

//capture the screenshot of the uiimageview and save it in camera roll
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.myUIView.frame.size);
[self.myUIView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; // tried this
[self.dView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];   //tried this
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];   //tried this
[topView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];   //tried this
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);

}
```

**I am calling this method on a button click in my view controller.**

I even tried capturing the window that is suggested from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964153/ios-whats-the-fastest-most-performant-way-to-make-a-screenshot-programaticall), still I dont get the result I get from screenhotting manually.

Is there any way to capture the top most view that is shown to user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this post: [Why don't added sublayers show up in screenshot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050020/why-dont-added-sublayers-show-up-in-screenshot)

Seems that sublayers aren't handled by the renderInContext method.

When you want to capture a screenshot try storing a frame from the preview layer in a UIImageView then you should be able to manually put that frame underneath your mask and just screenshot the superview.